# pip install mod-wsgi fails due to loading wrong libpython

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, building

I tried to install mod-wsgi using `pip install mod-wsgi` using a standard CentOS install of python3.6. I recieved an error saying that I needed to recompile python using `--enable-shared` as a flag for `./configure`.

Consequently, I downloaded and extracted the python 3.7 source code from here:
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tar.xz

I then ran `./configure --enable-shared --enable-optimizations LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /path/containing/lib"` (the rpath being the parent dir of `libpython3.7m.so`) followed by `make`.

At this point, I didn't want to run `make install` because I didn't want to pollute the system executable paths since I already had a python3 executable in my $PATH. I can, however, run the built python executable. I then wanted to proceed with `./python -m pip install mod-wsgi` and get slammed with a bunch of errors saying things like the following:

```
/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.a(bytes_methods.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol '_Py_NoneStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

after the following gcc line:

```
gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-rpath /etc/httpd/IDVPython \
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_thread.o \
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/mod_wsgi.o \
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_buckets.o \
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_memory.o \
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_interp.o \
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_restrict.o \
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_logger.o \
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_server.o \
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_convert.o \
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_metrics.o \
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_validate.o \
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_daemon.o \
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_apache.o \
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_stream.o \
-L. \
-lpython3.7m \
-o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py37.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so \
-L/usr/local/lib \
-L/usr/local/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-linux \
-lpython3.7m
```

This means that the pip install is loading libpython from `/usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.a` and not from
`/path/containing/lib/libpython3.7m.so`

**How do I make the pip install reference the correct shared library?**

---

EDIT:

`ldd ./python` confirms that python should be using the desired shared library:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffea0bfe000)
    libpython3.7m.so.1.0 => /etc/httpd/IDVPython/libpython3.7m.so.1.0 (0x00002acb63080000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002acb635b9000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002acb637d5000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00002acb639d9000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002acb63bdc000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002acb63ede000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002acb62e5c000)
```

Comment: I think you are missing the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable. You should add to it python libraries because pip is probably trying to compile something using the system gcc.

Comment: I ran `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/etc/httpd/IDVPython` (my desired path)  and that didn't fix it either.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I just renamed the `/usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.a` file so that when pip calls gcc, it wouldn't find this and copied the `libpython3.7m.so` from my python install to `/usr/local/lib`